# why Windows Service Control Manager takes minutes to process the request?

Tags: c++, windows, service, version-control

In my source code, the following code is to issue the "sc stop myservice" and "sc start myservice",

```
system(stopcmd.c_str());
Sleep(10*1000);
system(startcmd.c_str());
Sleep(10*1000);
```

But I notice that, looks like the service (myservice in the command) actually received the SCM event several minutes after the code above is executed.

What can result in such situation? Does that means the SCM is busy and cannot response the request above timely? or what else could be the problem?

Comment: What happens if you try the same commands from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Your Sleep is 10 second . in my Idea you have a do()while  some where . first kill all services . then trace your code . be suspicions about do while

Comment: Yes, there is a do()while, this piece of code is very deep in one of the function called in the do()while. But how can Sleep cause problem when placed in do()while?

Comment: maybe that code is not in thread . Do you have thread ? If not , at services you should have .

Comment: Yes, it is a multi-thread app, but the code is in a thread which will not create new thread. Does this matter?

Comment: I do not think so . i think stop commands wait until all threads get done and in one of them a do-while takes time to get down .